# multiple comma values in single csv file column

Tags: php, csv

I am not getting multiple , separate values in single column.Thanks for help

```
$fname = "vijay";
$mname = "a,b";
$csvData = "";
   $csvData .= "First Name";
    $csvData .= ",Middle Name";
    $csvData .= "\n\r";
    $csvData .= "$fname" . ",";
    $csvData .= "$mname";
    $csvData .= "\n\r";
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=student-report-data-" . date("dMY_H:i") . ".csv");
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: 0');
echo $csvData;
exit;
```

[image]

Comment: Use `fputcsv()`

Comment: above code use for dynamic download data in csv file  so where put   fputcsv() in code .filename=student-report-data-" . date("dMY_H:i") . ".csv"); create file at run time

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping them inside quotes.  Your second input's `,`'s are currently creating a new column rather than behaving how you want them to, stay inline.  I would recommend looking into http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php to make this less labor intensive.

```
$fname = "vijay";
$mname = "a,b";
$csvData = "";
     $csvData .= "\"First Name\"";
        $csvData .= ",\"Middle Name\"";
        $csvData .= "\n\r";
        $csvData .= "\"$fname\"" . ",";
        $csvData .= "\"$mname\"";
        $csvData .= "\n\r";
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=student-report-data-" . date("dMY_H:i") . ".csv");
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: 0');
echo $csvData;
exit;
```

If  you ever have a quote in your string you will have to add a `\` before the `"`, just a heads up.

Comment: Hey, if you could mark as solution, it helps a lot.  And I wish you the best.